# Reduce limit for ec2 instance in other region to zero

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, limit

By default the limit of ec2 instance in a region is 30, but we want to make to zero, for the regions we don't want to deploy for the time.

When I worked on console, I don't see any way to make limit to zero, there was option to increase our limit.  Probably I wasn't able to use google properly too.

How to reduce the limit of ec2 instance in region to zero.

Comment: There is no the setting in AWS management console, you need contact Amazon AWS engineer for help. But my feeling is, they also can't help you to set to 0 in some regions.

Comment: if the answer fulfills your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't limit the max EC2 instances by region in the way you describe, but you could setup a policy for a particular IAM user that restricted what regions they were allowed to created instances in - so you wouldn't limit the number they can create, but can prevent EC2 instances from being created at all except in the regions you allow.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html

For example:

```
{
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"allow",
    "Action":"RunInstances",
    "Resource":"*",
    "Condition":{
      "condition":{
        "ec2:Region":"us-east-1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That seems to nice way to do ...
So I can limit admin IAM user with every access other with explicit deny if he creates ec2 instance in other zone and use master account if I need to create ec2 in other zones . !